# extracting specific format elements from the list in c#

Tags: c#, list, reorderlist

how to separate (numeric elements and alphabetic elements) with (alphanumeric elements and elements with brackets like `[Constant 0.001]`) from a list into two separate lists.

like we have elements in

```
list<string> abc={'123','11','abcc','abdd','abcd11','abcd12',[abcd]}
```

after seprating elements in two lists..

```
list<string> abc1={'123','11','abcc','abdd'}  
list<string> abc2={'abcd11','abcd12',[abcd]}
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? It sounds like you're just asking us to do it for you.

Comment: Show us your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var abc = new List<string> { "abc", "123", "abd12" };

var alphaXorNumerical = abc.Where(str => str.All(Char.IsDigit) ||
                                         str.All(Char.IsLetter));

var others = abc.Except(alphaXorNumerical);
```

If you also want to check for whitespace, use this instead:

```
var alphaXorNumerical = abc
          .Where(str => str.All(Char.IsDigit) ||
                        str.All(ch => Char.IsLetter(ch) || Char.IsWhiteSpace(ch)));
```

Comment: the first list should also include the elements which are only letters.

Comment: @Matten My bad, fixed it

Comment: `[abcd]` (with brackets) would still go to the numerical collection, you could use char.IsLetter  ` abc.Where(str => str.All( Char.IsDigit) || str.All(char.IsLetter))`

Comment: @user2601862 Use the latest version, after the edits. Also, see here a working version: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jvblax

Comment: first time used this magical website for asking query.. and i am very much impressed.. thnx many times.. u people saved my hours of time..

Comment: @user2601862 If you found an answer helpful, click the up arrow to the left of the question to award some points to the user. If you found that this answer resolved your question entirely, click the check mark to indicate this.

Comment: so sad.. its workin on the list of <string> type but not with the list of any table type..where each elements in the list have several property and i want to apply the above sepration on the basis of its 'description' property values. ex. list<Itemtable> abc=new list<Itemtable>() ; abc.item, abc.description,abc.value,etc.

Comment: @user2601862 You should have mentioned that in your question. So, it's a list of `ItemTable`, and not strings? And the `ItemTable` type has a `Description` property, which is a string, right?

Comment: its doing good.. but here is a small problem that it is not able to take a string with blank space (like "hello Sir") in first list named 'numeric' and put that element in 'other' list.

Comment: @user2601862 I've updated the answer with a `Where` clause that also checks for whitespace. You might also want to use `IsPunctuation` or `IsSeparator`. Take a look at the `Char.Is...` methods here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx

Comment: NO!!  i don't want to check the blank spaces, in fact i want to check sting with a blank space(example "you helped" or "m thankful") and put that in the first list which is "alphaXorNumerical" .